# Disable and Refresh within same function jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

This isn't much of a problem but I'm wondering if theres a way I can turn this

```
$(".selector").sortable("disable").sortable("refresh");
```

into this

```
$(".selector").sortable("disable", "refresh");
```

Using disable and refresh within the same sortable function seems more efficient/simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if you can do that with the Sortable API, but if you can't you can always add the functionality youself using [`prototype`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp):

```
$.prototype.sortableDisableAndRefresh = function() {
    this.sortable("disable").sortable("refresh");
}

$(".selector").sortableDisableAndRefresh();
```

I'm not sure what kind of efficiency you are after. If you want it to run faster, this won't help. If you just want to make one function call to make the code pretty, it might.